# How to penalize a document for a particular value in solr?

Tags: solr, solr-boost

I am trying to implement a jobsearch in solr.
What I want is to boost the title and keyword field.
And also to negatively boost the those documents in which location is Anywhere.

For example :
I searched for "Perl" and Location "Mumbai"
The The result must contain all resumes with Perl in their title or keyword and location "Mumbai or Anywhere".
But Resume with Anywhere field must come Last.
I made the following query:

```
  ((((perl)) AND ( (perl) ttl:(perl)^5 kw:(perl)^2) ) 
 AND (( pref:(Mumbai)   (pref:Anywhere)^0.000000001)) )
```

But It is not giving proper result.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fake a "negative boost" is to give a large boost to everything that does *not* match. You can do this something like this with you query (not tested , so experiment with this) :

```
((((perl)) AND ( (perl) ttl:(perl)^5 kw:(perl)^2) ) 
 AND (( pref:(Mumbai)   (*:* -pref:Anywhere)^999 ) )
```

Here is more about it: `http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_do_I_give_a_negative_.28or_very_low.29_boost_to_documents_that_match_a_query.3F`

Comment: but I think it will also cancel out the boost on ttl and kw.Thus the document order will not be arranged as per ttl and kwd, reducing the relevancy.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: i do not think so, did you try it?

Comment: please elaborate a little.I am new to all this and if it works perfectly then it will a great relief.